# requestFeature() must be called before adding content in fragment class

Tags: android, fragment

i want use :

```
getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

but get this error :

requestFeature() must be called before adding content

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to request features required before setting any `View` to `Activity`, i.e before you call `setContentView()` in `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot call `requestFeature()` once you called `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting property of Activity in Fragment is not a good idea, isn't it?

Do it in YourActivity.onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

`requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` must be before super.onCreate in activity not in Fragment